# why we use max_value two times in this code?

Tags: java, recursion

1. Here max_value initialized as static variable once with the value of
   0 but why it is initialized again in the function leftView???
2. without initialize max_value in leftView function i have got my correct output when i
   run in vscode but when i submit it in gfg  without initialize max_value in leftView
   function i have got error why??

   ```
         //code snippet for print left view of binary tree
        /* Class to print the left view */
           class BinaryTree {
           Node root;
           static int max_level = 0;

           // recursive function to print left view
           void leftViewUtil(Node node, int level)
           {
               // Base Case
               if (node == null)
                   return;

               // If this is the first node of its level
               if (max_level < level) {
                   System.out.print(" " + node.data);//print node
                   max_level = level;
               }

               // Recur for left and right subtrees
               leftViewUtil(node.left, level + 1);//its goes to left side of node and do level+1 

               leftViewUtil(node.right, level + 1);//its goes to right side of node and dolevel+1 
           }

           // A wrapper over leftViewUtil()
           void leftView()
           {
               max_level = 0;
               leftViewUtil(root, 1);
           }

      }
   ```

Comment: What language is this? What does "gfg" mean? What is the error you get?

Comment: java , geeks for geeks, i just want to know why max_value initialized by 0 two times ??

Comment: Because the person who wrote this code wasn’t very good at programming, and didn’t understand how to write recursive functions properly.

Comment: if i intialize static variable with value 0 , so we don't need to  initialize it again in leftView function, am i right?

Comment: @Sneftel You could also blame java, which imposes "OOP" on people to a degree that they lose their minds. The whole thing should just be a function, but because Java, the author made it a class and was looking for some member to make it not look so empty :)

Comment: There are a ton of problems with this code. When you say it comes from geeksforgeeks, that does not remotely surprise me. Close that tab and never go back; that website has nothing but *terrible* advice and outdated practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what happens if there is only the `static int max_level = 0;` line at the top of the class:

1. The class is loaded, the static variable allocated in memory, and initialised to `0`
2. The recursive `leftViewUtil` method is called with `level` equal to `1`
3. The condition `if (max_level < level)` is evaluated as true: `0 < 1`
4. `max_level` is assigned the value `1`
5. Additional calls to `leftViewUtil` may pass in higher values of `level`, incrementing `max_level` further; none ever reduces it again

Now consider what happens if you run the function *a second time*:

1. The class is already loaded, so no additional initialisation takes place; `max_level` retains its old value (let's assume `1`)
2. The recursive `leftViewUtil` method is called with `level` equal to `1`
3. The condition `if (max_level < level)` is evaluated, but this time is checking `1 < 1`, so it is *false*
4. The whole thing goes wrong

By adding the extra assignment to `max_level` in the public `leftView` method, we *reset* the state on each call, ensuring the class is reusable.

There are, as others say, completely different implementations of the algorithm that don't use a static variable at all; but if you use one, you need to reset it each time you print a new tree.

Comment: ok after execution of each tree max_value need to reset 0  so for that reason max_value=0 use in leftView function, am i right ??